# Is there a way to prevent Jetty from sending a content length header on head requests?

Tags: servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to serve data to a device that doesn't like it when the HEAD request returns 0 as the content length. The actual GET response is chunked so I don't have a content length.

Jetty is adding that content length of 0 on its own. I tried using a `Filter` with `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to remove the header but none of the header methods got called for "Content-Length".

So is there some way to remove that header?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of jetty are you using?

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned that. `8.1.12.v20130726` and I'm kind of stuck on that one because of a dependency.

Comment: I've checked jetty 9 and the correct behaviour is implemented there.  Unfortunately jetty 8 is EOL and we are not doing any new releases (unless needed by a commercial client...).   If you wanted to attempt a fix yourself, then we'd be happy to accept a pull request on github and answer questions on mailing list / IRC to help you along.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fishy.

Filed a bug about it https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/596

Per the spec - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2

```
The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
send a message body in the response (i.e., the response terminates at
the end of the header section).  The server SHOULD send the same
header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if
the request had been a GET, except that the payload header fields
(Section 3.3) MAY be omitted.  This method can be used for obtaining
metadata about the selected representation without transferring the
representation data and is often used for testing hypertext links for
validity, accessibility, and recent modification.
```

So, if you request HEAD on a resource that's `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, there really is no `Content-Length` to be provided.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug.